# Use checkstyle configuration from plugin when generating eclipse files from maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, checkstyle

I have a common artifact where I store build-tools configuration files, e.g. checkstyle, pmd etc.

I can access the files and everything works as expected when I run from the console. The configuration files are included in my project and the reports are generated as expected when I run `mvn site` from the console.

However, files that are required by eclipse and should be included when `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is run are not to be found. I got an error telling me that the files cannot be found.

This is the important part of my POM.xml file:

```xml
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
      <configuration>
        <additionalBuildcommands>
          <buildcommand>net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleBuilder</buildcommand>
        </additionalBuildcommands>
        <additionalProjectnatures>
          <projectnature>net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleNature</projectnature>
        </additionalProjectnatures>
        <additionalConfig>
          <file>
            <name>.checkstyle</name>
            <location>${basedir}/eclipse-checkstyle.xml</location>
          </file>
        </additionalConfig>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

So my question is how to get maven to understand that these files, which is located in my build-tools artifact, to be included when I run the `eclipse:eclipse` command?

EDIT: It is the eclipse-checkstyle.xml that cannot be found.

Comment: Which files cannot be found - is it the `eclipse-checkstyle.xml` file?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is the eclipse-checkstyle.xml file that cannot be found.
It is included in the build-tools artifact, but not included in the main artifact's target folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the jar holding the relevant sources as a dependency of the plugin, not an extention:

```
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
      <configuration>
        ...
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```